# Laravel Authentication and routing with socialite

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing, laravel-socialite

Somebody please help me. I am trying to implement Socialite Authentication, everything works fine but routes under `Auth` is not working.They are redirect back to login page.What is problem with my `Auth` or Routes. My Route and Controller files are below

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('facebook',array( 
        'as' => 'facebook', 
        'uses' =>'FacebookController@redirectToProvider'
    ));
    Route::get('Callback', 'FacebookController@handleProviderCallback');
}); 
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web','auth']], function () {    
    Route::get('play', function () {
        return view('landing');
    });

    Route::get('go', function () {
        return view('landing');
    });
});
```

Controller

```
public function handleProviderCallback()
{
    try 
    {
        $user = Socialize::with('facebook')->user();
    } 
    catch (Exception $e) 
    {
        return Redirect::to('login');
    }

    $authUser = $this->findOrCreateUser($user);
    Auth::login($authUser, true);
    $user = Auth::user();
        return Redirect::to('play');       
}

    private function findOrCreateUser($facebookUser)
    {
        if ($authUser = User::where('id', $facebookUser->getId())->first()) 
        {
            return $authUser;
        }
        return User::create([
            'id' => $facebookUser->getId(),
            'name' => $facebookUser->getName(),
            'email' => $facebookUser->getEmail(),
            'gender' => $facebookUser->user['gender'],
            'avatar' => $facebookUser->getAvatar(),
            'avatar_original' => $facebookUser->avatar_original,
            'verified' => $facebookUser->user['verified']
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: First of all you have to set the domain name in config/session.php . Then clear your cache and try again.